# Is there ANY way to access the reference of a column in the form of an array from a matrix?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have been thinking of this for a while, but I couldn't come up with a solution. In java, we can access the reference of a row in a matrix like this:

```
int [][] matrix = new int[3][4];
int [] toChangeTo = new int[4];
matrix[0] = toChangeTo;
```

Here, if I will make any changes in `matrix[0]`, it will reflect in the actual matrix. However, there is no such way I could find to access a column. When I looked for some answers online, they were:

```
int [][] matrix = new int[3][4];
int column = new int[3];

for(int r = 0 ; r < matrix.length ; r++) {
    column[r] = matrix[r][0];
}
```

In this code, `column` does have the values of the first column of `matrix`, but it is not its reference. I want a way to access the reference of any column of a matrix and without for loop iterations. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that due to the memory layout.

Comment: A column doesn't exist. You would have to make a class that behaves the way you want. A two d array is actually a 1d array of objects, where each object is an array.

Comment: See the [official Java Tutorial entry on arrays:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) "[...] a multidimensional array is an array whose components are themselves arrays. This is unlike arrays in C or Fortran. A consequence of this is that the rows are allowed to vary in length[...]" - this makes it basically impossible to provide a column view of a multidimensional array in general, because not all rows need to have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[3][4]` means, I'll have a cupboard with three big boxes, then in each box, I'll put four smaller boxes. You can take a whole big box from the cupboard and have it still contain its four sub-boxes; but there's nothing that already contains the first sub-box of each big box, unless you manually rearrange it.

Same thing with Java.

Answer (score 1):

As for **any** way, we could create a class.

```
class Column{
    private final int[][] data;
    private final int column;
    public Column( int[][] data, int c ){
        this.data = data;
        column = c;
    }          
    int get(int i){
        return data[i][column];
    }
    int set(int index, int value){
        data[index][column] = value;
    }
}
```

We could add more methods like length etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hey as other mention there is no way you can do that. You can read about how matrix is create in memory. Each row is sequence of memory location horizontally.

If you want to set reference of column to two variable, just store column values in row and row values in column OR take transpose of matrix.